# Unexpected whitespace after jumbotron on mobile platforms

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

See it on: voiddevelopment.com

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Test Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menuCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">&lt;Void&gt;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menuCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid push-spaces">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="supporting">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="alignment: top;">
        <div class="col">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
            <h3>Professional Design</h3>
            <br />
            <p>Work with us to create the website design of your dreams.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-console"></span>
            <h3>Great Functionality</h3>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>
            <h3>Order Now</h3>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron{
    background: url("jumbotron.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    -webkit-background-size: 70%;
    -moz-background-size: 70%;
    -o-background-size: 70%;
    background-size: 70%;
    margin-top: 0 auto;
}
.push-spaces {
    height: 550px;
}
.supporting {
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.supporting .col {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.supporting .glyphicon {
    font-size: 4em;
}

.supporting .col h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

On all mobile platforms, there is a odd whitespace showing up between the jumbotron image and the supporting content. This is odd because I did not add any. Perhaps some CSS tag to pull up the supporting content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a div called .push-spaces that's 550px high , a class of container-fluid, which has a margin of 0 auto it is causing the white space.

Comment: they are contained within jumbotron

Comment: So I should override the margin within the push-spaces class?

Comment: why do you have the container there at all?

Comment: The main issue I'm trying to solve is a way to have the jumbotron background image resize responsivly just like " <img src="jumbotron.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; width: 80%;">" would, however have the ability for me to write something over it.

Comment: it ends up ruining the aspect ratio of the image, changing the height and width at different rates. The image ends up looks like its very poor quality.

Comment: hmmm, well you can size it to like 50% 75% or something, i would play with background size., only in media queries though

Comment: the image or the container?

Comment: image but only in media queries

Comment: I appoligize, but I'm not really sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being the solution:

```
<img src="jumbotron.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; width: 80%;">
```

Just changed the jumbotron to an image. Realized that I didn't need text over it anyway.